# Caffe file solver.prototxt gives no keys for bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel

Tags: caffe

I am triying to compile the following model :

http://manutdzou.github.io/2016/12/27/FCN-segmentation.html

but I got the eror :

------->  KeyError: 'fc6_my'

When I look to  :   solver.net.params.keys()

I get the output :  odict_keys([ ])

I don't know why is giving no keys for the object :   solver.net.params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layer names are actually specified in the model definition file i.e. often train_val.prototxt but not in the solver.prototxt.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I still do not understand what I am doing wrong when I call :  solver.net.params.keys()